# An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later + linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

Have linkedin AUTH2.0 and it was working fine before but now a day one of the url on the site stopped working.
http://failover.resolvit.com/Mobile/Careers/JoinOurTeam/tabid/447/jobid/9869/Software-Architect-Blue-Ash-Ohio.aspx

-It giving error: 
"An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later "

But same block of code working fine on same website on another URL
http://failover.resolvit.com/Careers/JoinOurTeam/tabid/437/language/en-US/Default.aspx
- It worked fine.
Not able to produce on local instance if produce some sort of same environment as well.

Any help appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Linkedin has updated its API terms of use, 
create the new app and use its credentials

LinkedIn has started a partnership program to use APIs, you need to sign in for it.

**Linkedin Post:**
Starting May 12, LinkedIn will only offer a handful of its APIs for general use, namely those that allow users and companies to post information about themselves on the service. Since then, only companies that have enrolled in LinkedIn’s partner program will have API access. Samsung, WeChat, and Evernote have already struck such partnerships.

Answer (score 1):

A month ago i created new app on developer account. I have access to check `r_fullprofile` and its working. Two days before I'm not able to login through linkedIn in my app. Today i created new app it shows me only `r_basicprofile`, `r_emailaddress`, `rw_company_admin` and `w_share only`.To get `r_fullprofile` you have to submitted form to request permission for more fields access.

https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr

Comment: On February 12th 2015 we announced a series of changes to our developer program.

see this linkedIn official link

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition